# "If he were" or "if he would be"?

Tags: reported-speech

**Direct:**

> He said, "If I were a bird!"

**Indirect:**

> ***** He wished that he **would be** a bird.

OR

> ***** He wished that he **were** a bird.

I'm confused whether the former or the latter is correct.

My textbook indicates the **former one,** but it sometimes has mistakes.

Comment: It's the second.

Answer (score 1):

Your textbook has made another mistake.  The second sentence is fine.  The first sentence actually changes the meaning slightly.

For the subjunctive, you can use either "was" or "were" (there's [considerable discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44706/was-or-were-in-subjunctive-clauses) about which is OK to use, if you are interested):

> I wish I **were/was** a rich man.

"Would be" is more associated with *conditional* statements, even those that express purely hypothetical possibilities:

> **If** I could be anything I wished, I **would be** a rich man.

This doesn't change when shifted to indirect speech

> Tevye said he wished he **were** a rich man.
>
> Tevye said that if he could be anything he wished, he **would be** a rich man.

Comment: Sure, there is some discussion, but linguists (people who study the language as it is used by its native speakers) agree that the choice between *was* and *were* is in fact entirely stylistic (see the comments by users Colin Fine and Barry England under the tendentious (biased), top-voted answer to the linked question). Learners shouldn't worry about this distinction at all – *was* is completely fine in informal English (i.e., the style everyone uses everywhere except in very formal situations) – it's only native speakers who raise this issue since there aren't many such dilemmas in English.

Comment: @userr2684291  I would rather say there are hundreds of such dilemmas in English, Many of the learners here are actually quite well educated in their own language, and are relieved to know that they aren't going crazy when they are taught two seemingly contradictory grammar rules from two different sources.   What's tedious and trivial to you may be of great interest to a dedicated English student.

Comment: Even Italian has the Subjunctive mood. I find rather "strange" saying that language learners should not be interested in using it correctly.

Comment: @kiamlaluno As I said, the distinction at hand is a matter of style, which, by the way, is tertiary when it comes to expressing your thoughts in any language. Just because native speakers of English were taught that one thing wrong, doesn't mean learners of English are supposed to be worrying about it. The only thing strange (no quotes necessary) is pushing that particular question on ELU where the top-voted answer is tendentious. English has but a single remnant of the subjunctive mood – an exception; it's therefore by and large wrong to claim that English has a subjunctive mood at all.

Comment: @userr2684291There are other details that are less important for learners (who aren't all at the same level), for example if English has really a future tense. I don't see what is so boring about knowing that _if I were rich_ can have a different meaning.